# Need Help Getting Floating Social Bar Working

Tags: javascript, css, facebook-social-plugins

My client is using the "Digg-Digg" plugin on their blog, and has asked me to implement the same thing on the rest of the site. I have copied the html code, the css file & the JS file, updated the links and variables, yet it still won't appear on the page. Can anyone help me out??? Thank you in advance.

Here is the html code:

```
<a id="dd_end"></a>
<div class='dd_outer'>
<div class='dd_inner'>
<div id='dd_ajax_float' style="position: absolute; top: 308px; left: -95px; display: block;">
<div class='dd_button_v'>
<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://www.scottera.com/" data-count="vertical" data-text="Arch Kit" data-via="archkit" ></a><script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script></div><div style='clear:left'></div><div class='dd_button_v'><script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="http://www.scottera.com" send="false" show_faces="false"  layout="box_count" width="50"  ></fb:like></div><div style='clear:left'></div><div class='dd_button_v'><script type='text/javascript' src='https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js'></script><g:plusone size='tall' href='http://www.scottera.com/'></g:plusone></div><div style='clear:left'></div></div></div></div><script type="text/javascript">var dd_offset_from_content = 40;var dd_top_offset_from_content = 0;var dd_override_start_anchor_id = "";var dd_override_top_offset = "";</script><script type="text/javascript" src="include/digg-digg/js/diggdigg-floating-bar.js?ver=5.3.6"></script>
```

And here is the CSS for the main sections:

```
.dd_outer {

width:100%;

height:0;

position:absolute;

top:0;

left:0;

z-index:9999
```

}

.dd_inner {

```
margin:0 auto;

position:relative
```

}

EDIT: Adding JS code:

```
    var dd_top = 0;
var dd_left = 0;

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    var $floating_bar = jQuery('#dd_ajax_float');

    var dd_anchorId = 'dd_start';
    if ( typeof dd_override_start_anchor_id !== 'undefined' && dd_override_start_anchor_id.length > 0 ) {
        dd_anchorId = dd_override_start_anchor_id;
    }

    var $dd_start = jQuery( '#' + dd_anchorId );
    var $dd_end = jQuery('#dd_end');
    var $dd_outer = jQuery('.dd_outer');

    // first, move the floating bar out of the content to avoid position: relative issues
    $dd_outer.appendTo('#wrapper');

    if ( typeof dd_override_top_offset !== 'undefined' && dd_override_top_offset.length > 0 ) {
        dd_top_offset_from_content = parseInt( dd_override_top_offset );
    }
    dd_top = parseInt($dd_start.offset().top) + dd_top_offset_from_content;

    if($dd_end.length){
        dd_end = parseInt($dd_end.offset().top);
    }

    dd_left = -(dd_offset_from_content + 55);

    dd_adjust_inner_width();
    dd_position_floating_bar(dd_top, dd_left);

    $floating_bar.fadeIn('slow');

    if($floating_bar.length > 0){

        var pullX = $floating_bar.css('margin-left');

        jQuery(window).scroll(function () { 

            var scroll_from_top = jQuery(window).scrollTop() + 30;
            var is_fixed = $dd_outer.css('position') == 'fixed';

            if($dd_end.length){
                var dd_ajax_float_bottom = dd_end - ($floating_bar.height() + 30);
            }

            if($floating_bar.length > 0)
            {
                if(scroll_from_top > dd_ajax_float_bottom && $dd_end.length){
                    dd_position_floating_bar(dd_ajax_float_bottom, dd_left);
                    $dd_outer.css('position', 'absolute');
                } 
                else if ( scroll_from_top > dd_top && !is_fixed )
                {
                    dd_position_floating_bar(30, dd_left);
                    $dd_outer.css('position', 'fixed');
                }
                else if ( scroll_from_top < dd_top && is_fixed )
                {
                    dd_position_floating_bar(dd_top, dd_left);
                    $dd_outer.css('position', 'absolute');
                }

            }

        });
    }

    // Load Linked In Sharers (Resolves issue with position on page)
    if(jQuery('.dd-linkedin-share').length){
        jQuery('.dd-linkedin-share div').each(function(index) {
            var $linkedinSharer = jQuery(this);

            var linkedinShareURL = $linkedinSharer.attr('data-url');
            var linkedinShareCounter = $linkedinSharer.attr('data-counter');

            var linkedinShareCode = jQuery('<script>').attr('type', 'unparsed-IN/Share').attr('data-url', linkedinShareURL).attr('data-counter', linkedinShareCounter);

            $linkedinSharer.html(linkedinShareCode);

            IN.Event.on(IN, "systemReady", function() {
                $linkedinSharer.children('script').first().attr('type', 'IN/Share');
                IN.parse();
            });
        });
    }

});


jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    dd_adjust_inner_width();
});

var dd_is_hidden = false;
var dd_resize_timer;
function dd_adjust_inner_width() {

    var $dd_inner = jQuery('.dd_inner');
    var $dd_floating_bar = jQuery('#dd_ajax_float')
    var width = parseInt(jQuery(window).width() - (jQuery('#dd_start').offset().left * 2));
    $dd_inner.width(width);
    var dd_should_be_hidden = (((jQuery(window).width() - width)/2) < -dd_left);
    var dd_is_hidden = $dd_floating_bar.is(':hidden');

    if(dd_should_be_hidden && !dd_is_hidden)
    {
        clearTimeout(dd_resize_timer);
        dd_resize_timer = setTimeout(function(){ jQuery('#dd_ajax_float').fadeOut(); }, -dd_left);
    }
    else if(!dd_should_be_hidden && dd_is_hidden)
    {
        clearTimeout(dd_resize_timer);
        dd_resize_timer = setTimeout(function(){ jQuery('#dd_ajax_float').fadeIn(); }, -dd_left);
    }
}

function dd_position_floating_bar(top, left, position) {
    var $floating_bar = jQuery('#dd_ajax_float');
    if(top == undefined) top = 0 + dd_top_offset_from_content;;
    if(left == undefined) left = 0;
    if(position == undefined) position = 'absolute';

    $floating_bar.css({
        position: position,
        top: top + 'px',
        left: left + 'px'
    });
}
```

Comment: You've posted your html and css, yet poorly written html or css wouldn't stop it from showing completely. If it isn't showing at all then it's a JS issue.

Comment: That's what I thought, but as I said it's copied from the JS used in the plug in, so it doesn't make sense as to why it works on the blog but not the static pages. I'll add the JS above.

Comment: Can anyone point out what is wrong with the JS???

Comment: The js seems ok, a link to the site would be required to fix this problem.

Comment: The current URL is scottera.com (it's a test server); you can see that the plugin version works on the blog but it's not working on the home page, which is where I'm trying to get it to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the floating social bar plugin

http://wordpress.org/plugins/floating-social-bar/ (it is my plugin)

There is an option to manually add the floating bar on all WordPress pages if you want. Just look at the code on the FAQ page.

Comment: The rest of the pages aren't part of Wordpress, they are regular PHP pages.